# How to Instal windows after ubuntu ?

Tags: windows

I accidentally removed my windows when I install ubuntu.
How to install windows after ubuntu?
and how to make memory partition in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Windows and just don't re-format the Ubuntu Partition. (If its the whole disk, shrink it down and make space for windows)

Windows will delete Grub bootloader tho, so after installing windows use this tool to re-create GRUB bootloader

http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

Then use GParted to shrink a partition down and format the space as SWAP (Memory Partition)

PS: A usual rule is same amount of SWAP as RAM up to a certain point like 4GBS, after that I don't think you need SWAP really or definitely don't need 8GB Swap (Its used when RAM is full)

A good program also if you want to keep Windows Boot loader, look into EasyBCD to add Ubuntu to Windows Bootloader options.